# Php tried to connect the mysql server. and server reject the connection connection for user control as defined has failed

Tags: phpmyadmin

i am using Mac XAMPP my local server is running fine but my phpmyadmin is not connecting it was working fine few minutes ago as you can see my server and phpmyadmin is running fine.
[image]

***but i am having this error***
[image]